# Please specify the product's required option error when add to cart using ajax

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I am using Ajax for add to cart a product. But If I am on the configurable product page, then my ajax response to this error. 'Please specify the product's required option'. This is my code for add to cart.

```
$cart->addProduct($product, array(
'qty' => $qty
));
```

If I am on the simple product page then that product is adding from ajax without any error.